# Avoid raising Setting with copy warning

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

Suppose I have a dataframe df with columns a, b, c, d and I want to subtract mean of the columns from columns a,b,d. How do I achieve the same?

I have tried `df[['a','b','d']] = df[['a','b','d']] - df[['a','b','d']].mean()` but I get SettingWithCopyWarning. How do I achieve the same without the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to modify a slice of the dataframe directly, e.g., df[['a','b','d']], this can lead to unexpected behavior if you're not careful. Thus, this warning arises to carefully warn you that the original dataframe is being changed by doing this copying process. To suppress this warning, you can use:

```
mean = df[['a','b','d']].mean()
df[['a','b','d']] = df[['a','b','d']] - mean
```

or

```
df.loc[:, ['a','b','d']] = df[['a','b','d']] - df[['a','b','d']].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

df[['a','b','d']] is a like view of original dataframe...trying to set values in a view may or may not work everytime

do it seperately

```
df['a']=df['a'].mean()
df['b']=df['b'].mean()
df['d']=df['d'].mean()
```

its doesn't make much  difference in performance

Comment: Or `[df[x] = df[x].mean() for x in ['a', 'b', 'd']]` for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the warning at that statement/line ?

Anyways, In a *Pandorable* way and to reduce visible noise, I would do :

```
cols = ["a", "b", "d"]

df[cols] = df[cols].sub(df[cols].mean())
```